# Why is my pygame application not responding?

Tags: python, pygame

So I need to create a little game for a school exercise. I'm too lazy to create all the screens in code so I just made png's of all of them and then called them "spelfase" 0, 1 and 2 in my code. Spelfase 0 is the startscreen showing the title of the game and whatnot. Spelfase 1 is the rulescreen showing the rules. Spelfase 2 is the actual game. 
I'm fairly sure that the code of spelfase 1 is the problem because when I put that code in, my application didn't respond when I pressed the spacebar when I was on the startscreen.

I'm really new to coding so I haven't tried very many things.

```
spelfase = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while not done:
    if spelfase == 0:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                done = True 
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    spelfase = 1

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    bordrect = startscherm.get_rect() 
    screen.blit(startscherm, bordrect)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
while not done:
if spelfase == 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done = True 
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                spelfase = 2

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    bordrect = regelscherm.get_rect()
    screen.blit(regelscherm, bordrect) 
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
while not done:
    if spelfase == 2:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True 
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                print ("Knop: Spatie")

                worp = random.randint(1,6)
                posities[beurt] += worp
                if posities[beurt] >= 63:
                    posities[beurt] = 63
                if beurt == 0:
                    beurt = 1
                else:
                    beurt = 0

            elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                print ("Knop: Backspace")
                beurt = 0
                worp = 0
                posities = [0,0]

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    bordrect = bord.get_rect()
    screen.blit(bord, bordrect)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: `done` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey hi sorry it is defined earlier in the code but i didnt put it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your not leaving the first loop because if you press space your still not "done"

```
spelfase = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while not done:
    if spelfase == 0:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                done = True 
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    spelfase = 1

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    bordrect = startscherm.get_rect() 
    screen.blit(startscherm, bordrect)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
if spelfase == 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done = True 
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                spelfase = 2
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    bordrect = regelscherm.get_rect()
    screen.blit(regelscherm, bordrect) 
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
    if spelfase == 2:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True 
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                print ("Knop: Spatie")

                worp = random.randint(1,6)
                posities[beurt] += worp
                if posities[beurt] >= 63:
                    posities[beurt] = 63
                if beurt == 0:
                    beurt = 1
                else:
                    beurt = 0

            elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                print ("Knop: Backspace")
                beurt = 0
                worp = 0
                posities = [0,0]
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    bordrect = bord.get_rect()
    screen.blit(bord, bordrect)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

This is a quick fix but  you ned to remove those if statements and clean things up

Comment: basically you only need one while not done loop put everything in there